# Summation over a sympy Array

Tags: python, sympy

I want to sum over a sympy `Array` (called `arr`) using the two indices `i` and `j`. Summing over `arr[i]` results in an integer as `In [4]` below shows. However, summing over `arr[j]` does not give a number as result (see `In [5]` below). Why is that?

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: i, j = symbols("i j", integer=True)

In [3]: arr = Array([1, 2])

In [4]: summation(
   ...:     arr[i],
   ...:     (j, 0, i), (i, 0, len(arr)-1)
   ...: )
Out[4]: 5

In [5]: summation(
   ...:     arr[j],
   ...:     (j, 0, i), (i, 0, len(arr)-1)
   ...: )
Out[5]: Sum([1, 2][j], (j, 0, i), (i, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy will evaluate summation if either

1. Both the summand and the limits for summation are explicit; or
2. It can find a symbolic expression for the sum, based on the formula for the summand.

Nested summation is performed from left to right. In the first version,

```
summation(arr[i], (j, 0, i))
```

falls under item 2: since the summand does not depend on the index `j`, the sum evaluates to symbolically to `(i + 1)*arr[i]`. Then the outer sum becomes

```
summation((i + 1)*arr[i], (i, 0, len(arr)-1))
```

and this falls under item 1: both the summand and the limits are explicit.

But in the second version,

```
summation(arr[j], (j, 0, i))
```

fits neither 1 nor 2. The summand depends on j, we don't have any formula for it (it's just some numbers [1, 2]), *and* the upper limit of summation is symbolic. There is nothing for SymPy to do with such a sum, so it remains undone. Subsequently, the outer sum is not going anywhere since the inner was not done.

#### Workaround

In the second case, replacing the outer sum with Python sum makes the inner one explicit, so it gets evaluated.

```
>>> sum([summation(arr[j], (j, 0, i)) for i in range(len(arr))])
4
```

Of course, this does not really use symbolic capabilities of SymPy: the inner sum could be Python's `sum` as well.