# How to calculate the sum of the sequence without using built-in functions for exponentiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, sympy, exponentiation

I need to calculate the sum of the sequence in Python
but I can't use the built-in functions for exponentiation.

It means I can't use `**` and `pow()`. I have to create my own function for that.

So I created the function for exponentiation but it works only for numbers. I need to calculate my formula to the nth.

My function for exponentiation:

```
def exponentiation(a,b):
    result = 1
    for index in range(b):
        result = result * a
    return result
```

For numbers, it works. But when I want to do this to the nth (I defined 'n' as a Symbol) I get:

```
'Symbol' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So I don't know how to fix that.

And if I want to calculate the sum of the sequence, I use and it works:

```
sy.summation((-1/2)**n, (n,1, oo))
```

But as I said before I need to change `**` to my own exponentiation function, but it still shows that 'Symbol' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

```
sy.summation(exponentiation((-1/2),n), (n,1, oo))
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: What exactly is the result of exponentiation with a symbol?

Comment: @eugenhu yes, I use sympy

Comment: @martineau I get an error: TypeError: 'Symbol' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: _It means I can't use `**` and `pow()`._ - Why?

Comment: @PatrickArtner it's a part of the task. It means calculate the sum of the sequence without using built-in functions for exponentiation.

Comment: Minimalist: Yeah, I know — you mentioned that already. The misunderstanding was because there was no mention that you were using sympy. I just added the tag to your question.

Comment: So you are allowed to use SymPy but not **, pow() ? This seems to be a XY-Problem. You seem to want to calculate the limes of the function (-1/2)**n for n in 0 ... infinity. - you can not "calculate" infinite things with a loop, your code would never finish, you need some break condition for a OR need to find a closed solution.

Comment: @Mr.T for exponentiation(2,3) I get 8 - it works. When I do for example exponentiation(2,n) I get an error that symbol object cannot be interpreted as an integer - I did only for the test. When I do: sy.summation((-1/2)**n, (n,1, oo)) I receive 1/3. So I need to calcucate this sum without  built-in functions for exponentiation but I want to recive 1/3 too.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense, since in this case ** is not a python build-in, but a function (__pow__) that is implemented by SymPy.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I use SymPy to calculate the sum of the sequence (sy.summation). So do you think that my  function for exponentiation is wrongly defined?

Comment: @AnnoSiedler I can't use any function to calculate the exponentiation (**, pow(), etc) I need to create my own one.

Comment: Check with your teacher. How high are the chances you are allowed to use SymPy if you are forbidden to use **?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I only got the instruction that I have to calculate the sum of the sequence (-1/2)^n but I can't use prepared commands in Python for raising the number to integer power. and I need to create my own function for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'nth' means any given number. So you don't need to (and I can't think how you would) exponentiate any symbols. I think you can maybe simplify things a bit, if you return a list instead of just the nth value:

```
def exponentiation(a, n):
    result = 1
    exponents_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        result *= a
        exponents_list.append(result)
    return exponents_list
```

then work with the list with a for loop to get your sum

if you have to work with sympy, check this answer: [Summation over a sympy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723550/summation-over-a-sympy-array)

Comment: it doesn't work.  I need to change that: summation((-1/2)**n, (n,1, oo)). -  I have to replace ** with my own function. The function you wrote doesn't work because it gets "Sum(n**(-0.5), (n, 1, oo))" and the result should be 1/3.

Comment: `print(sum(exponentiation(-.5, 64)))` returns roughly -1/3 (-0.33333333333333337)

Comment: That's assuming you're allowed to use the builtin `sum()` function. Otherwise, use a for loop as in the exponentiation function.

Comment: it's assumed you will take https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html into account

Answer (score 2):

You cannot raise 'n' to a power. I am pretty sure if you are forbidden to use `**` and `pow()` using SymPy won't fly either.

To calculate what [image: limes n formula] results in you can simply assume a "big" n and check if you can still detect any difference between the earlier result and the next result - you will not see any more changes very fast due to floating math limitations ([Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)):

> ```
> def exponentiation(a,b):
>     result = 1
>     for index in range(b):
>         result = result * a
>     return result
> ```

```
s = 0
a = -1/2
for n in range(1, 10000000):
    old_s = s
    s += exponentiation(a,n)

    # do not compare floats with small differences with ==
    # see link below for better ways to do that
    if s == old_s:
        print("\nThe sum no longer changes due to floating math limitations.")
        print(f"Result before: {old_s} and after {s} for n={n}")
        break
    else:
        print(f"nResult before: {old_s} and after {s} for n={n}")
```

Output:

```
Result before: 0 and after -0.5 for n=1
Result before: -0.5 and after -0.25 for n=2
Result before: -0.25 and after -0.375 for n=3
[...snipp...]
Result before: -0.33333333333333326 and after -0.33333333333333337 for n=53
Result before: -0.33333333333333337 and after -0.3333333333333333 for n=54
Result before: -0.3333333333333333 and after -0.33333333333333337 for n=55

The sum no longer changes due to floating math limitations.
Result before: -0.33333333333333337 and after -0.33333333333333337 for n=56
```

See [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for more on float comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, the only meaningful solution to replace `**` with Python-code is something like that:

```
def exponentiation(a,b):
    if isinstance(a, Symbol):
        return a.__pow__(b)
    if isinstance(b, Symbol):
        return b.__pow__(a)
    result = 1
    for index in range(b):
        result = result * a
    return result
```

If you want to re-implement SymPys **pow** function - that'd be certainly far too difficult for a Stackoverflow-answer ;).

But you can find SymPys source code here:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/power.py